# Can't build Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Get the following error when doing a build.  I get the "Build Succeeded" message for the source code but apparently something is going wrong when trying to output the source files.  Anyone got any ideas?

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: 

Error: Tool exited with code: 1. Output: unknown output extension: obj/Debug/android/bin

usage:
  dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
  [--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
  [--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
  [--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
  [--num-threads=<n>] [--incremental] [--force-jumbo]
  [<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] 

...Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
    jar/zip. 

Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk. 

Positions
    options: none, important, lines.

  dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
  [--print=<print types>]
  dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
  [--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
  [--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
    Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
  dx --find-usages <file.dex> <declaring type> <member>

Find references and declarations to a field or method.
    declaring type: a class name in internal form, like Ljava/lang/Object;
    member: a field or method name, like hashCode
  dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
    Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
  dx --version
    Print the version of this tool (1.7).
  dx --help
    Print this message.
 (Zint.AddIt.Forms.Droid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Xamarin Studio -> Preferences -> Projects -> SDK Locations -> Andorid was pointing to a directory that I was no longer using for the more recent SDK updates.  Changed it to point to the correct SDK directory and build succeeded.